# Is there a way to extract the Key and Field values from a dictionary into separate variables?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value-store

I have a dictionary with items that look like this:

```
{'33515783': [('ID', '33515783'),
('Location', 'madeuptown'),
('Address1', ' 1221 madeup street')],..etc
```

Is there a way to have the Key values (33515783) be in a separate variable and then everything in the list from [('ID' -------street')] in another variable ?

so for example:

Variable 1: 33515783

Variable 2: [('ID', '33515783'),
('Location', 'madeuptown'),
('Address1', ' 1221 madeup street')]

I was able to get the Variable 1 (Keys) correctly using this:

```
for x in d:
  ID = x
```

But I do not know what to do for the field portion.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: `x` is the key, and `d[x]` is the value.

Comment: hi! thanks for explaining that. I tried to do a loop for that but it only recorded the first value. do you have any tips on how to make it go through each pair?

Comment: figured it out thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dictionary.items()` to get key, value pairs and unpack them with a loop to get them seperately in two variables. Something like this.

```
a = {'33515783': [('ID', '33515783'),
('Location', 'madeuptown'),
('Address1', ' 1221 madeup street')]}

for key, value in a.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
33515783
[('ID', '33515783'), ('Location', 'madeuptown'), ('Address1', ' 1221 madeup street')]
```

Comment: Hi Delta! thank you I figured it out from the previous comment by John. I appreciate your time! this is a very interesting way to do it as well!

Comment: accept my solution so we can close the thread as it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Per advice from responses. I did the below and it worked for me:

#This got the results into a separate list (variable).

```
res_1 = list()
for x in d:
 A = d[x]
 res_1.append(A)
```

Thanks everyone.